# Error al pasar de Consulta SQL Server a Linq C#

Tags: c#, linq

```
SELECT c.CompanyName, ca.CategoryName, p.ProductName, SUM(od.Quantity * od.UnitPrice * (1 - (od.Discount))) as Importe
from Customers c inner join Orders o on c.CustomerId = o.CustomerId
                inner join [Order Details] od on o.OrderId = od.OrderId
                inner join Products p on od.ProductId = p.ProductId
                inner join Categories ca on p.CategoryId = ca.CategoryId
group by c.CompanyName, ca.CategoryName, p.ProductName
ORDER BY c.CompanyName;
```

```
public static void Example04()
        {
            //Obtener un listado por clientes y productos que nos han comprado
            //Cliente   Categoría   Producto    Importe
            //Ordenado por Cliente, Categoría, Producto
            var dbContext = new NeptunoContext();

            var lista = dbContext.OrderDetails
                .OrderBy(od => od.Order.Customer.CompanyName)
                .ThenBy(od => od.Product.Category.CategoryName)
                .ThenBy(od => od.Product.ProductName)
                .Select(od => new
                            {
                                Cliente = od.Order.Customer.CompanyName,
                                Categoria = od.Product.Category.CategoryName,
                                Producto = od.Product.ProductName,
                                Importe = (dbContext.OrderDetails
                                                .GroupBy(i=>i.Product.Category.CategoryId)
                                                .Where(o=>od.ProductId == od.Product.ProductId)
                                                .Sum(i => od.Quantity * od.UnitPrice * (1 - (decimal)od.Discount))
                                                
                                                
                                              ),
                                Veces = 0
                            }
                        );

            int counter = 0;
            foreach (var item in lista)
            {
                counter++;
                Console.WriteLine(counter + "\t\t" + 
                                item.Cliente + "\t\t" +
                                item.Categoria + "\t\t" +
                                item.Producto + "\t\t" +
                                item.Importe + "\t\t" +
                                item.Veces);
                Console.WriteLine("");
            }

        }
```

A ver si me pueden echar una mano , estoy practicando con la BBDD Nepturo(Northwind) y con C# Linq.
No consigo realizar la consulta que os muestro en SQL a Linq C#.

La consulta sería :
Obtener un listado por clientes y productos que nos han comprado
con los campos --> Cliente,   Categoría,   Producto,    Importe.
Ordenados por Cliente, Categoría, Producto.

El problema lo tengo a la hora de realizar el Importe... no sé plantear la consulta para conseguir el resultado correcto.

Gracias.

Comment: Si hablás de un error, entonces mencioná el error _específico_ que estás teniendo. No saber cómo hacerlo no es un error... Leé [ask] y haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio.

Comment: No es un error lo que me aparece. Mi duda es plantear correctamente la consulta en Linq para calcular el importe, según la consulta de SQL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cuando una consulta Linq es más enredada que la SQL es signo que algo estamos haciendo mal.

Cuando el modelo está bien implementado, los `inner join` de SQL se convierten en propiedades de navegación (por eso es importante tener el modelo bien configurado)

Por ejemplo, tienes UN objeto `orderDetails` y quieres obtener el nombre de la compañía haces:

```
var NombreCompania = orderDetails.Order.Customer.CompanyName;
```

Los join existen en Linq, pero se usan cuando estas propiedades de navegación no existen. Muy común en análisis de datos cuando no hay tablas relacionadas. Los otros tipos de join también son posibles de implementar, usando diversas técnicas.

Tu consulta queda de esta manera

```
var lista = from od in dbContext.OrderDetails
            group od by new 
            { 
                od.Order.Customer.CompanyName, 
                od.Product.Category.CategoryName, 
                od.Product.ProductName 
            } into p 
            orderby p.Key.CompanyName
            select new
            {
                Cliente = p.Key.CompanyName,
                Categoria = p.Key.CategoryName,
                Producto = p.Key.ProductName,
                Importe = p.Sum(x => x.Quantity * x.UnitPrice * (1 - x.Discount)),
                Veces = p.Count()
            };


Console.WriteLine("|            Cliente             |       Categoria      |        Producto        |    Importe    |   Veces   | ");
Console.WriteLine("==============================================================================================================");
foreach (var item in lista)
{
         
    Console.Write("|{0,32}|", item.Cliente);
    Console.Write("{0,22}|", item.Categoria);
    Console.Write("{0,24}|", item.Producto);
    Console.Write("{0,15}|", item.Importe);
    Console.Write("{0,11}|", item.Veces);
    Console.WriteLine("");

}
```

Si yo hubiera escrito el `select` y el `group by` usando una sola línea, como haces tú en la sentencia SQL habría ocupado 4 líneas versus las 7 que ocupas tu SQL. Porque casi siempre es más corto usar linq. Esto para mi es una de las grandes ventajas, quien no ha tenido que lidiar con consultas monstruosas??

Otro punto, es que yo agrupé exactamente igual que tu consulta SQL, es decir por nombres de categoría, producto y cliente. Pero bien podría haber agrupado por el objeto mismo (od.Order, od.Product) o por su Id, donde este último caso podría ser más eficiente (habría que comprobarlo).

Comment: Muchas gracias por la respuesta tan amplia y concisa.

Comment: Muchas gracias @Yussef por la respuesta tan amplia y concisa. La versión que me has descrito creo que se denomina Lambda Expression y después de tus comentarios me queda muy claro su funcionamiento. Ahora tengo la duda de si es posible realizar lo mismo pero como yo lo tenia enfocado.  Un saludo y gracias nuevamente.

Comment: @Oscar_pp No entendí muy bien lo que solicitas. Yo escribí una expresión Linq (tal como pides en el título de tu pregunta), y ahora que me fijo bien, en el contenido de la misma lo que tu escribiste está con expresiones Lambdas. En la práctica se utilizan ambas sintaxis: juntas, separadas e incluso revueltas, dependiendo de cómo mejores la legibilidad del código. Si por algún motivo tú quieres la versión Lambda, me parece que deberás hacer otra pregunta, porque esta que has hecho dice "LINQ". Te recuerdo que si mi respuesta te pareció de ayuda puedes marcarla como aceptada. SALUDOS!!

Comment: Perfecto, entendido. Gracias por todo @Yussef.